# How to ADD datetime and timer in seconds?

Tags: sql, groovy

I have a datetime in the format **2018-01-24 14:45:14.7340000** and  a variable called timer for example **6214.0751953125** in seconds. I have declared timer in float. My datetime is from the sytem transaction

> java.sql.Timestamp

which is having its own format in datetime in sql. I am trying to add this datetime and my timer which is in seconds and to get the output called End_time in  **2018-01-24 14:45:14.7340000** this format. I am getting a format error because of adding a datetime + timer_sec(float). Please guide me through this !

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
String startDate='2018-01-24 14:45:14.7340000'

Float addtime=6214075.1953125 // Milliseconds

Date sdate = Date.parse( 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', startDate )

println ((sdate.getTime()+addtime).getDatestr())
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **TimeCategory**. It is very usefull tool to manipulate with dates in groovy:

```
def time = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
float timer = 6214.0751953125
def (secs, millis) = timer.toString().tokenize('.')*.toInteger()

use(groovy.time.TimeCategory){
   def newTime = (time + secs.seconds + millis.milliseconds).toTimestamp()
}
```